# Save sent and receive email with identifier C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I wrote a C# form application, that can send and receive emails using Outlook 2013. I used with MAPI namespeace.( "Outlook._NameSpace _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");").
**My problem is: How create Identifier for email?**
I would like save it into an sql database table and later recognize if table already contains this mail. 
I had found mail.CreationTime and mail.SenderEmailAddress, but after send method(in code last rows), mail is already empty.
Thanks any helps.

I send my send message code:

```
     Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
 Outlook._NameSpace _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
 Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = _ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
 Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
 mail.To = ActEmail.To;
 mail.CC = ActEmail.CC;
 mail.Subject = ActEmail.Subject;
 mail.Body = ActEmail.Body;
 mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
 if(ActEmail.Attachments.Count != 0)
 {
 foreach (Attachment item in ActEmail.Attachments)
 {
 mail.Attachments.Add(item.Attachment1, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, item.Attachment1);//.Substring(item.Attachment1.LastIndexOf('\') + 1));
 }
 }
((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
 string theString = mail.CreationTime + mail.SenderEmailAddress;
```

Comment: Take a bunch of the unique properties (sender, recipient, subject, body, creation date, etc.), concatenate them, and hash the result using SHA-1 or MD5. `MailItem.EntryID` is volatile and cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MailItem.EntryID`. Note that it will change if the message is moved to a different folder.

Comment: You may use MailItem.conversationIndex